# Should This Company’s ‘Fraud’ System Work Both Ways?

Tags: fraud

*** Let me preface this by saying that I understand why I was banned after reviewing the terms of service. I'm not looking for fault-finding, but rather, I'm curious if there's a potential case against the company due to their flawed fraud system that seems to favor their profit by allowing multiple deposits from the same PayPal account on different app accounts without flagging it before the money leaves the paypal account.

I’ve been playing games for cash on an app whose parent company is AviaGames. I had spent money on this app (via paypal) initially and then realized that the games are easier to win when you’re new on the app (how they get users hooked). Upon realizing this, I created a new account on this app and deposited money (using the same paypal account on my other account). Upon accumulating some winnings, I decided to withdrawal my balance back to my paypal account, but was blocked due to ‘fraud’. Instead of flagging my paypal account during the deposit process, they accepted my money and then banned me upon trying to withdrawal. Shouldn’t their system work to detect a duplicate paypal account in their system before the second account tries to deposit money? Instead of after they’ve already pocketed that money?

Answer (score 1):

Almost every contract/user agreement I've seen includes terms that basically say if the company – for any reason – at one time fails to enforce part of the contract, that "failure" will not prevent it enforcing the contract in the future, where "for any reason" either explicitly or implicitly covers both them not noticing that you broke the rules, or them choosing not to enforce the rules (on that specific occasion).

I strongly suspect that a company would point to such clauses if a case were brought against them under the conditions you describe.

Comment: Also, the company might argue that the claimant has 'unclean hands' (acted unethically to create the circumstances that they are complaining about).